# Why are there no LINQ extension methods on RepeaterItemCollection despite the fact that it implements IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, repeater, linq-to-objects

Why are there no LINQ extension methods on RepeaterItemCollection despite the fact that it implements IEnumerable?

I'm using Linq to objects elsewhere in the same class.  However, when I attempt to do so with the RepeaterItemCollection they aren't available.  I was under the impression that the LINQ extension methods were available to classes that implement IEnumerable.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you missing a `using` in the file that you're attempting to do this in?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<T>`.

That doesn't mean you can't use it though - that's part of what [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) and [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) are for, building a generic sequence from a nongeneric one:

```
var filtered = items.Cast<RepeaterItem>()
                    .Where(...) // Or whatever
                    .ToList();
```

In this case `Cast` is more appropriate than `OfType` as you should be confident that it will only contain `RepeaterItem` values. Note that `Cast` is what gets used if you state the type of a range variable in a query expression, so this will work too:

```
var query = from RepeaterItem item in items
            where item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem
            select item.DataItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

It would need to implement the generic `IEnumerable<>` to work with LINQ, which is does not.

You can, however, "cast" it first to the type you need with the [`Cast<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method.

Comment: Yes, it looks like this class was born in .NET 1.0 so does not know generics.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritemcollection_methods.aspx), it has the following 4 extension methods:

- `AsParallel()`
- `AsQueryable()`
- `Cast<TResult>()`
- `OfType<TResult>()`